# Problems with function checking if a path exists or not

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am a little new to bash scripting and I was trying to make this program capture a directory path from user and then check if the directory is present. It seems as if the variable `SRC` inside the `dir_input` function is not passed to `dir_input`. Thanks in advance.

```
dir_input() {
    echo -n "Enter targer directory: "
    read SRC
}
dir_input_check() {
    if [ ! -d "$SRC" ]; then
        echo ERROR: "Target directory not found - Please try again."
        dir_input
    fi
}

dir_input
dir_input_check
```

Comment: How exaxtly do you run the script?

Comment: Re "Seems like the variable SRC inside the dir_input function does not passes to dir_input." The calue in SRC does not come from the variablr in dir_input. It's direct nre input.

Comment: It seems to work for ma, as far as I see - can you show a test that shows something gors wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me.  Adding a

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

at the top to get a trace, I see this (if I enter `/tmp` in reply):

```
> ./foo
+ dir_input
+ echo -n 'Enter targer directory: '
Enter targer directory: + read SRC
/tmp
+ dir_input_check
+ '[' '!' -d /tmp ']'
```

So `SRC` is passed as expected to `dir_input_check`.  Perhaps there is something left out of the example.